# MySQL Connector C/C API - Query with special characters

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-connector

I a C program I have a function that takes in parameter a domain name:

```
void db_domains_query(char *name);
```

With mysql_query() I test if the domain name is existing in a database. If it's not the case, I insert the new domain name:

```
...
char *query[400];

sprintf(query, "SELECT Id, DomainName FROM domains WHERE domainName LIKE '%s'", name);
if (mysql_query(con, query))
finish_with_error(con);

MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);
    if (result == NULL)
        finish_with_error(con);

    MYSQL_ROW row;
    if ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
        printf("Element exists : %s %s\n", row[0], row[1]);
    else
        printf("Element %s doesn't found\n", name);
        // Then insert the new domain name ...
```

This portion of code works perfectly if *name* contains only "normal characters". However, for domain names that contain "special characters" the query seems incorrect even if those are in the database for instance :

- name = undaben.de : `Element exists : 100 undaben.de`
- name = ®here.com : `Element ®here.com is not found.`
- name  = §travel.us  : `Element §travel.us is not found.`

  Extract of the table :

  | id | domainname |
  | --- | --- |
  | 100 | undaben.de |
  | 162 | §travel.us |
  | 197 | ®here.com |

The collation of the field *domainname* is utf8_unicode_ci.
So how can I pass to mysql_query all domain names including the "special" ones ?

Comment: `Element ®here.com doesn't found.` lol wtf. Change that to `Element ®here.com isn't found.`

Comment: That is no valid code. At the very least the `sprintf` statement is missing double quotes for the string.

Comment: @jjmontes  Indeed, it's a typping error but obviously I use the sprintf statement with double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to avoid the C API unless you have a compelling reason to use it. The C++ API es way more usable.

You are embedding your arguments within your query string. This has a number of problems, including security risks. If you insist in this approach, in order to prevent problems with parameters messing with your query, you need to ensure a few things:

- Make sure that your data encoding matches the encoding of the MySQL Client connection (this may be different from your database encoding). If your connection is set up as UTF-8, then you need to make sure that special characters such as © are encoded also in UTF-8 when used as input to the `sprintf` function.
- You also need to protect from other SQL escape characters (like `'`). For this you can use the `mysql_real_escape_string` function, as mentioned in [Efficiently escaping quotes in C before passing to mysql_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839734/efficiently-escaping-quotes-in-c-before-passing-to-mysql-query).

However, you should very likely be using **prepared statements** which circumvent these issues. You still need to make sure that your input data encoding matches the encoding of your client connection, but everything else shall be easier to handle.

I paste an example of a parameterized query using the C API with prepared statements looks like (example from http://lgallardo.com/2011/06/23/sentencias-preparadas-de-mysql-en-c-ejemplo-completo/). Note the example is for integers, not strings, you need to adapt to your use case.

```
 sql = "select count(*) from addresses where id = ?";

 // Open Database
 openDB(&conn);

 // Allocate statement handler
 stmt = mysql_stmt_init(conn);

 if (stmt == NULL) {
  print_error(conn, "Could not initialize statement handler");
  return;
 }

 // Prepare the statement
 if (mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, sql, strlen(sql)) != 0) {
  print_stmt_error(stmt, "Could not prepare statement");
  return;
 }

 // Initialize the result column structures
 memset (param, 0, sizeof (param)); /* zero the structures */
 memset (result, 0, sizeof (result)); /* zero the structures */

 // Init param structure
 // Select
 param[0].buffer_type     = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
 param[0].buffer         = (void *) &myId;
 param[0].is_unsigned    = 0;
 param[0].is_null         = 0;
 param[0].length         = 0;

 // Result
 result[0].buffer_type     = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
 result[0].buffer         = (void *) &myNumAddresses;
 result[0].is_unsigned    = 0;
 result[0].is_null         = &is_null[0];
 result[0].length         = 0;

 // Bind param structure to statement
 if (mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, param) != 0) {
  print_stmt_error(stmt, "Could not bind parameters");
  return;
 }

 // Bind result
 if (mysql_stmt_bind_result(stmt, result) != 0) {
  print_stmt_error(stmt, "Could not bind results");
  return;
 }

 // Set bind parameters
 myId            = id;

 // Execute!!
 if (mysql_stmt_execute(stmt) != 0) {
  print_stmt_error(stmt, "Could not execute statement");
  return;
 }

 if (mysql_stmt_store_result(stmt) != 0) {
  print_stmt_error(stmt, "Could not buffer result set");
  return;
 }

 // Init data
 (*numAddresses) = 0;

 // Fetch
 if(mysql_stmt_fetch (stmt) == 0){
  (*numAddresses) = myNumAddresses;
 }

 // Deallocate result set
 mysql_stmt_free_result(stmt); /* deallocate result set */

 // Close the statement
 mysql_stmt_close(stmt);

 // Close Database
 closeDB(conn);
```

Again, if you can use some other client library (like the C++ client) your code will be way shorter and readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it helps me better understand my issues. Unfortunately, I can only use C language. Then I will try the prepared statement method to resolve my query.  One more thing, concerning the data-encoding, all my C source files are in UTF-8. But, I get my data (the name variable) from a UTF-8  text file (which is itself an extract copied from a US_ASCII text file) that I read with the getline function and I store the readed data (still from the UTF-8 file) into a char ** in my C program. So, I don't get it , why data are still not properly encoded ?

Comment: The symbols you mention (ie ©) are not part of the standard ASCII set so you may have encoding issues somewhere in the line. © is ASCII-Extended number 184, whereas in UTF-8 that byte is a different character (¸). My guess is that you are not actually sending proper UTF-8 encoded strings. Also make sure your MySQL client is using UTF-8 (this can be done using `CharSet=utf8;` in the connection string).

Answer (score 0):

My bad, as @jjmontes mentioned it seems that the sent string was encoded in `'latin1'`.

Using the function  `mysql_set_character_set(conn, "utf8")` before doing the query solved this problem.
Now, I will try to use **prepared statements** instead of query strings.

thanks again!