# How does my C program insert a string into a mariadb database which contains a character > 0x80

Tags: c, utf-8, mariadb

My C program attempts to insert a string into a Mariadb Database:

```
sprintf(query,"INSERT INTO text(drawing, eID, txt) VALUES(%s,%ld,'%s');",drawing_number,element_handle,txt);
mysql_query(sqlconnect,query);
```

If the txt string does not contain character > 127, then it works fine.

However, if the string contains the degree character, for example (°, 0xB0), then the string is not inserted into the database, as far as I can tell, without any error.

GDB shows that the query is submitted correctly for the string without the character:

> (gdb) p query
>
> $7 = 0x5555555a1dd0 "INSERT INTO text(drawing, eID, txt) VALUES(6,1000699,'FOR DETAILS OF');"

But for the string containing the degree character, this is what GDB shows me:

> (gdb) p query
>
> $8 = 0x5555555a1dd0 "INSERT INTO text(drawing, eID, txt) VALUES(6,1000700,'SUCTION BOX 22\260');"

If I search the database using "`select * from text where drawing=6 and txt like 'SUCTION BOX%';`" or "`select * from text where drawing=6 and eID=1000700;`" it returns an empty set.

The database schema is 'utf8mb3'.

Clearly the string is not being encoded correctly, so how do I ensure that it is correctly encoded?

This can't be a unique problem, but I can't seem to find the solution (very likely I'm using poor search strings), so I hope you'll forgive the duplication.

The suggested solution appears to query a database with unicode characters using C. As far as I can tell the row is not actually being inserted into the database in the first place. I can insert the row manually: `INSERT INTO text(drawing, eID, txt) VALUES(6,1000700,'SUCTION BOX 22�');`.

It is clearly not being encoded by my compiler. gcc version 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04).

My research had indicated that the **char**  datatype was automatically assigned as utf8 by default. Am I wrong in assuming this to be the case?

The original text is in a fixed wide character format of two bytes, least significant byte first. I don't think this is a normal wc format, though, as my attempt to use wctombs() failed.

Comment: UTF-8 requires more than one byte to encode non-ascii characters such as the degree sign.  You presumably need to encode your non-ascii characters as proper UTF-8 sequences.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Connector C/C API - Query with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304629/mysql-connector-c-c-api-query-with-special-characters)

Comment: You didn't set your [client character set](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/wiki/mysql_set_character_set)

Comment: You should also use bound parameters instead of `sprintf()`. See full example for MariaDB C API here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/bulk-insert-column-wise-binding/

Comment: For latin1, the degree sign is hex B0.  For utf8, it is hex C2B0.  You must specify the encoding of the _client_ either in configuration or during the connection.  (That is where the problem is.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused the utf-8 char array being incorrectly assigned.

I created an array of wchar_t and filled it with the original array (which comprised 2 bytes, least significant byte first).

```
   for(int i=0;i<sz;i++){
     ut[i]=(s[ii++])&0xFF;
     ut[i]+=((s[ii]&0xFF)<<8);
     ut[i]&=0xFFFF;
     ii++;
     if(!ut[i])
       break;
   }
```

Then I used `wctombs` to convert my newly created array to chars.

```
  char *rt;
  rt=(char *)malloc(sz*2);
  wcstombs(rt,ut,sz);
  return rt;
```

This worked.

I'm not sure why, but the format of the original array was incompatible with the conversion tools.

I'm sure there's a better way and will freely acknowledge that my coding is awfully clumsy, but I wanted to close this question out.

Many thanks to all those who replied.