# How can I prevent SQL injection in C using a prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, c, prepared-statement, code-injection

I have to protect my software from SQL Injection.

Here is an example of my C code:

```
char myquery[QUERY_LEN];
sprintf(myquery, "select * from patient p where p.id_doc='%s'", us_names[index].name);

if (mysql_query(conn, myquery )) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    exit(1);
}
```

I want to use prepared statement, because I read that is the best solution, but I don't understand how it works.

I used Google but I didn't find any example in C.

Can you make me an example with my code?

Comment: Did you read the manual?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html (section 19.8.4 onwards).

Comment: MySQL manual has an example: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html

Comment: Use placeholders; don't include the string directly in the SQL.  If you must, use the appropriate function to escape characters that need escaping.  Note that in C you need to be concerned about buffer overflows (as well as SQL injection).  So, you should probably be using `snprintf()` and also checking that the result means 'no overflow occurred'.

Comment: Thank you all for your advices

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to SO. You won't find complete examples for **your** code. Just generic examples. If you want to learn more about prevention of code injection, then google for that topic, not for your specific problem.

Some articles:

- [how to prevent SQL Injection in c language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515161/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-c-language)
- [SQL Injection Attacks and Some Tips on How to Prevent Them](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlInjectionAttacks.aspx)
- [SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: ok thank you!!! i find the solution here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html