# How to sanitize SQL queries in C?

Tags: mysql, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preventing SQL Injection in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827344/preventing-sql-injection-in-c)

I know PHP has some built in functions that help to sanitize queries, but does C have anything like that?

```
snprintf(&buff[0],1023,"UPDATE grades SET grade='%c' WHERE username='%s'",choice,&uname[0]);

if (mysql_query(connect,&buff[0]) != 0) {
  // If it failed, tell the user
  printf("Error: %s!\n", mysql_error(connect));
  return;
}
```

Comment: I'm almost sure there's some API that supports prepared statements.

Comment: As @cHao said, avoid input "sanitization" and go with prepared statements, the C API [supports them](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MySQL C API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html) has a [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) function.

Comment: After passing the query through that function, I get... "UPDATE grades SET grade=\'A\' WHERE username=\'student\'" This results in a syntax error when I try to execute it with mysql_query.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using this method of manually escaping strings, because the day you forget to call this is the day you introduce a security problem in your code. Always use prepared statements with bound parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The C language and runtime have no such routine. Your particular database's particular client library might have something.