# MySQL C API - Prepared statements vs. escaping input

Tags: mysql, c, prepared-statement

I'm building a C application, and for the first time using the MySQL API. I did a little research before I began building my application and stumbled upon [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827344/preventing-sql-injection-in-c), which talks about not putting user data directly into queries and instead using prepared statements to overcome the possibility of SQL injection - which is just fine and dandy.

I've come round to actually coding my application and I feel like I want to slit my wrists. I haven't used prepared statements before (it's so different to what I'm used to doing normally in my other favourite language, PHP - I'm so used to just writing SQL and escaping data). It so happens that I've also stumbled across the function [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html). **My question is - is it just as safe to escape data in an SQL query (an example below) as it is in a prepared statement?**

```
mysql_real_escape_string(dbc, sBuf, sUserInputData, strlen(sUserInputData));
sprintf(sQuery, "SELECT * FROM `sessions` WHERE `SessionID`='%s';", sBuf);
```

Comment: You should probably use `snprintf` rather than `sprintf`. As is, you have a buffer overflow vulnerability.

Comment: I think you should instead use prepared statements also in PHP - besides being at least as secure as escaping (if the escape function isn't bugged), it should also be slightly faster (you avoid the escaping and de-escaping costs, just transmitting the raw data separately from the query).

Comment: Absolutely prepared statements. Printf can be evil. If you are using c++ use of string stream can be useful too. Better some more security than just 10 nanoseconds less of computation :)