# pass stored int value to mysql table in C

Tags: c, int

I wrote a code in C for reading a sensor. From that sensor I get a int value. I stored that int value in a int variable called ''val''.

Now I want to sent the value stored in "val" to a table in a mysql database.
I just keep getting 0 in my database. I don't know why.

Here is the code:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{   int val;  // val is a variable of type integer

CPhidgetInterfaceKitHandle ifKit =0;
CPhidgetInterfaceKit_create(&ifKit);

CPhidget_open((CPhidgetHandle)ifKit,-1);

CPhidget_waitForAttachment((CPhidgetHandle)ifKit,1000);
//Waiting max 1000ms till phidgetkit is connected.

while(1)
{
CPhidgetInterfaceKit_getSensorValue(ifKit,0,&val);
//Reading sensor 0 and stores value in variable val.
// &val = pointer to the memory location of val

if(val > 65){
CPhidgetInterfaceKit_setOutputState(ifKit, 0, 1);
}
else{
CPhidgetInterfaceKit_setOutputState(ifKit, 0, 0);
}

MYSQL *conn;

char *server = "*****";
char *user = "*****";
char *password = "*****";
char *database = "*****";

// Make the connection to the Mysql-database.
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
     user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
  exit(1);
}

//Add values to table IRSensor
if (mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO IRsensor VALUES('val')" ))
  {exit (1);} 

printf("Value %d \n", val);
// Shows decimal value of val in terminal

usleep(800000); // delay of 800 ms before the sensor starts reading the next value
}

CPhidget_close((CPhidgetHandle)ifKit);
CPhidget_delete((CPhidgetHandle)ifKit);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO IRsensor VALUES('val')` your code inserts the litteral string `'val'`, are you sure that's what you want to do ?

Comment: No, I want to sent the int value stored in val but how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually surprised that works (and doesn't throw an error). You need to actually interpolate `val` into your INSERT command, not just use the string `'val'`.

But don't just do this naively: use a parameterized query, as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827344/preventing-sql-injection-in-c).